# Include dashboard inside Aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, aura

How can I insert a dashboard inside an custom aura component? In app builder the option is available to insert a dashboard but how to add the dashboard inside a custom aura component?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: it is not possible as of now.

Comment: but there are few app exchange products that are doing the same with tableau dashboard.

Comment: i am not sure about that but normally its not possible